# SSRS / Report Viewer - parameters greyed out / reports not rendering

Tags: sql, reporting-services, iis-7, reportviewer

Our production server did an automatic update last week and since then we have issues with our reporting.  No code has changed whatsoever.

The setup is we have SSRS2008 reports that are viewed via a reportviewer control (version 10).  Server has IIS7 and SQL2008R2.  Since the updates we have 2 scenarios:

For reports without any parameters the loading icon appears for a few seconds, then goes away but nothing is rendered.  You can see the report viewer control toolbar etc (all disabled) and white space where the report should be.  No Errors.

For our reports with dependant parameters you can select the first parameter and thereafter the other parameters are all greyed out and you cant make a selection.  Also no errors.

All reports run ok from within report manager.

Not sure if its related but after the update, the server restarted and after that the SQL Server service would not start - gave an error.  Turned out we had to disable the VIA protocol in the SQL Server Configuration Manager.  Once we did this the service started but also no idea why this occurred as we have never changed protocols etc.

From the reporting services log:

`Unhandled exception: Microsoft.ReportingServices.Diagnostics.Utilities.ReportServerHttpRuntimeClientDisconnectionException: A client has disconnected from the Report Server Web service application domain ReportManager_MSSQLSERVER_0-2-130461711338880624. No corrective action is required. An error code has been submitted to ASP.NET to release the connection. The error code is 800708CA. ---> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: This network connection does not exist. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x800708CA)`

Any help would be MUCH appreciated!

Comment: is this Browser specific or happening in all Browser like IE, Firefox, Chrome ..

Comment: Happens across all browsers

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried running the report in ReportViewer.aspx ?

This could be a variation of the

> 'Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object' error

bug. It occurs  when you have more than 1'000 parameters in a MULTIVALUE dropdown, and is brought to you by a SQL-Server security update.

You can solve it by adding aspnet:MaxHttpCollectionKeys to the web.config entries (your application & ReportServer):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>   
<configuration xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/.NetConfiguration/v2.0">



  <appSettings>
    <add key="aspnet:MaxHttpCollectionKeys" value="50000"/>
```

Otherwise I'd look at the server version and figure out if service-pack 2 is missing.

Comment: Tried to add the maxhttpcollectionkeys but no luck.

Comment: In the reporting services logfiles we get the follow error:Unhandled exception: Microsoft.ReportingServices.Diagnostics.Utilities.ReportServerHttpRuntimeClientDisconnectionException: A client has disconnected from the Report Server Web service application domain ReportManager_MSSQLSERVER_0-2-130461711338880624. No corrective action is required. An error code has been submitted to ASP.NET to release the connection. The error code is 800708CA. ---> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: This network connection does not exist.

Comment: @user3699212: Do you have sufficient permissions for the DNS name resolution ?